# Category removal - Portfolio Category:

Tags: categories

I am having trouble removing the "Portfolio Category:" text on this page http://www.dpwilliams.com/project-category/abstract/ which is automatically added to the headline.

Is there a way to add a function that removes this? I have seen some other answers but they do not seem to work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that text is coming from your theme.

I would create [a child theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/) (you'll only need `style.css` to start with), then copy whatever file it's coming from (probably `header.php` but could be in another file, possibly `single.portfolio.php`) into your child theme. From there, remove the whole section of code that looks something like this:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title">Portfolio Category: Abstract</h1>
    <div class="taxonomy-description"><p>These works are created using photographic and digital processing techniques.</p></div>
</header>
```

The actual code will include some PHP that's dynamically adding the correct category and description, but the main thing is to remove everything between `<header>` and `</header>`.